# Precache Firebase JS files with Workbox - blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, service-worker, workbox

I'm making a PWA that uses Google Firebase as a backend. I've setup Workbox to make my Service Worker, and it's precaching all the files I need correctly... except the firebase JS files from gstatic.com. I'm using Onsen UI and Workbox manages to precache the Onsen 3rd party files, so it must be something to do with Firebase's.

These are the HTML tags that include the Firebase files:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.0.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

And this is the Workbox service worker so far:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js');

if (workbox) {
  console.log(`Yay! Workbox is loaded `);
} else {
  console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
}

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
    '/index.html',
    '/auth.js',
    '/script.js',
    'https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css',
    'https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.min.css',
    'https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js',
    '/__/firebase/7.0.0/firebase-auth.js',
    'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-app.js',
    'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-firestore.js',
    'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-analytics.js'
]);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
    new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'image-cache',
    })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /\.(?:js|css|html)$/,
    new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'src-cache',
    })
);
```

This is one of the errors in the console when I try to run it:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-app.js' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Can anoyone tell me how to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, isn't Firebase's as such. Your error message tells that the gstatic.com server doesn't provide CORS headers for that resource. Without that CORS header, workbox won't be able to inspect responses for that resource. That makes caching very difficult.

There's some discussion about what you're trying to do here (precache from a CDN) on [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/604) for workbox. The relevant sentence is:

> One complication is that this should only work if the CDN supports CORS, because precaching opaque responses and serving them cache-first isn't a good practice.

The [workbox doco](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests#cross-origin_requests_and_opaque_responses) talks more about this caching and opaque responses issue:

> This response would cache the opaque response and serve it up from that point onwards. The problem is that if that request fails for any reason, Workbox won’t be able to detect this and will continue to serve up the broken response. The user will be in a broken state.

In your case, *if* you could force workbox to cache the resources from the CDN (I don't think you can) then there's a chance that it would cache an error response or at the very least workbox wouldn't know when a new version of the resource is available because it can't inspect the response.

## Option 1

If you're using something like webpack to bundle your code, then you could *not* use the CDN but instead bundle the [firebase code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) in with your app. You can look at using a [build tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/precache-files#generating_a_precache_manifest) to automatically generate the precache manifest.

## Option 2

Remove those `crossorigin="anonymous"` attributes from the `<script>` tags in your html file. And then remove those bottom 3 items from your precache manifest (for gstatic.com/firebase...). This means that you won't need the CORS headers but also that those files won't be precached in the PWA sense. They should still be cached by your browser though, so it will hopefully still work.

On a side note, I'm also developing a PWA using Onsen :D

Comment: That’s great, thanks for that! Option 2 seems to work for me so I’ll go with that method.